# Google Street View - disable street name on arrows

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have a panorama view. I show the arrows with "linksControl: true", but how to disable the street name of this arrows? I used v3 of API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing and was being an idiot about it.  It turns out to be quite easy with a very simple css rule.  If you have this markup:

```
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="pano" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
</body>
```

You simply add this css rule:

```
#pano text {
    display: none;
}
```